# Strange MS Access Union Issue: Union is not actually union

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

Using MS Access with a SQL Server back end, I have one table basically storing groupings of the Parameter field from another table.

For example, I have the parameters stored in TBL_Parameter: (Just a very small subset of the data)

```
Parameter
Iron (Fe)
Iron (Fe)-Dissolved
Iron (Fe)-Total
```

The table, TBL_ParentParameter looks like this:

```
Parent        Child
Iron (Fe)     Iron (Fe)-Dissolved
Iron (Fe)     Iron (Fe)-Total
```

Then I want to create a query to combine all parameters not contained as a child in TBL_ParentParameter with all the ones that are contained in TBL_ParentParameter, so I made the following union query:

```
SELECT Parameter, Parameter AS Child
FROM TBL_Parameter
WHERE Parameter NOT IN(SELECT Child FROM TBL_ParentParameter)
UNION
SELECT Parent AS Parameter, Child
FROM TBL_ParentParameter
```

This has the expected results of:

```
Parent        Child
Iron (Fe)     Iron (Fe)
Iron (Fe)     Iron (Fe)-Dissolved
Iron (Fe)     Iron (Fe)-Total
```

But instead gives:

```
Parent               Child
Iron (Fe)            Iron (Fe)
Iron (Fe)-Dissolved  Iron (Fe)-Dissolved
Iron (Fe)-Total      Iron (Fe)-Total
```

Now each query within the union query works perfectly fine individually, but when unioned, they don't work properly. I have tried this exact same query as a passthrough query directly to the SQL server, which works just fine, but if I base other queries on this query, I find that it can take a few times longer to run. So does anyone have any idea what the issue is here? Is this some sort of MS Access bug? Or am I looking at this wrong?

SOLVED: It appears that this is a bug with MS Access, and reversing the order of the two union subqueries fixed the issue.

Comment: Do you mean to say, this does NOT have the expected results of? (above the penultimate chunk of code)

Comment: What is the result if you change to `UNION ALL`?

Comment: Or if you reverse the order of 2 unioned subqueries?

Comment: It does not, which is why I find this all so weird. I have simplified it a bit, as TBL_Parameter has a few more fields for default units, etc, but that shouldn't make a difference. By the way I am using MS Access 2010 with a .mdb file for compatibility, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Ok, I revered the order of the subqueries and it seems to work... wow that's odd.

Comment: Then it's a bug. Welcome to Access-land :)

Comment: Haha. I wish I could say this was the first bug I've run into with access... but not even close.

Comment: @NinjaMeTimbers: Please post your solution as an answer and select it as the correct answer to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this is a bug with MS Access, and reversing the order of the two union subqueries fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is correct. I ran it and I got the penultimate chunk of code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it has to do with your aliasing the `Parameter` field as `Child` in the first query.  Then when you reference `Child` in the second query Access assumes you want to use your aliased definition of `Child` from the first query (ie, the `Parameter` field).

While reversing the order of the queries in the UNION may fix your problem, it seems you may run into problems in the `Parent` field when you have more than one possible value for `Parent`.

A better solution would be to fully qualify your field names (or simply use Aliases that don't conflict with existing fields):

```
SELECT P.Parameter, P.Parameter AS Child
FROM TBL_Parameter AS P
WHERE P.Parameter NOT IN (SELECT SubPP.Child FROM TBL_ParentParameter AS SubPP)
UNION
SELECT PP.Parent AS Parameter, PP.Child
FROM TBL_ParentParameter AS PP
```

Comment: At one point I thought it might have to do with aliasing, but changing them didn't seem to help. I plugged in your solution there too just now and ran into the same problem unfortunately.